# How to get the exact points (Rect) of TextView after rotation

Tags: android, rotation, textview

I'm trying to get the exact place of text in textview, I've got the text's position in textview by this code, when rotation is 0', 180', 360'

fTranslationX and fTranslationY are event.getX and event.getY of MOtionEvent

```
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    rect.left = (int) fTranslationX;
    rect.top = (int) fTranslationY;
    rect.right = (int) (fTranslationX + getTextWidth());
    rect.bottom = (int) (fTranslationY + getLineHeight());
```

My TextView is customized, so after rotation I can't get the rotated Rect, my text is rotated but the Rect remains at same points!!
How do I get rotated text's Rect in TextView (TextView's width=height = fill_parent)

any idea?